# Why is my Clojure code running so slowly?

Tags: clojure

Below is my answer for 4clojure [Problem 108](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/108)

I'm able to pass the first three tests but the last test times out. The code runs really, really slowly on this last test. What exactly is causing this?

```
((fn [& coll] (loop [coll coll m {}]
    (do
        (let [ct (count coll)
                ns (mapv first coll)
                m' (reduce #(update-in %1 [%2] (fnil inc 0)) m ns)]
            (println m')
            (if (some #(<= ct %) (mapv m' ns))
                (apply min (map first (filter #(>= (val %) ct) m')))
                (recur (mapv rest coll) m'))))))
 (map #(* % % %) (range)) ;; perfect cubes
 (filter #(zero? (bit-and % (dec %))) (range)) ;; powers of 2
 (iterate inc 20))
```

Comment: Are you sure this ever returns? I am suspecting something here is greedier than it should be on those lazy inputs. FYI my solution to this problem is 6 lines, does not use reduce or hashmaps at all, and does a lot less work than this. I'm not saying this to brag, but to say that your solution is much more complicated than the problem is.

Comment: @noisesmith I'm not sure--didn't have the patience to see if it would. I assume it would finish as an earlier test, which the code does pass, also uses infinite seqs (`(range) (range 0 100 7/6) [2 3 5 7 11 13])`).

Comment: note that it should, by the definition of the problem, return 64, which should be at most 44 iterations (the last arg being the one that takes longest to reach that number)

Comment: BTW, why are you using mapv instead of map? mapv is not lazy.

Comment: @DiegoBasch Confusion on my part. Looks like `map` works fine too. Doesn't address the problem at hand though.

Comment: @Chris also, your function is not lazy. You're counting coll. You can't count infinite collections.

Comment: @DiegoBasch `coll` is not an infinite seq. Coll in the example above is a seq of 3 seqs.

Comment: @DiegoBasch all of the reduce, count and mapv are being run on the indefinite argument list, not any of the lazy inputs.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong, you get stuck in an infinite loop. Why don't you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @DiegoBasch the loop isn't infinite, it's just very slow (due to the way the pwoers of two are being generated, and how eagerly he is asking for the next value in the sequence)

Comment: Correct. One thing that might help for this exercise: imagine how you'd do it with cards. Suppose you have stacks of sorted suits, with some missing cards. You look at the first card from each stack: what do you need to discard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are gathering the next value from every input on every iteration `(recur (mapv rest coll) m')`

One of your inputs generates values extremely slowly, and accellarates to very high values very quickly: `(filter #(zero? (bit-and % (dec %))) (range))`.

Your code is spending most of its time discovering powers of two by incrementing by one and testing the bits.

You don't need a map of all inputs with counts of occurrences. You don't need to find the next value for items that are not the lowest found so far. I won't post a solution since it is an exercise, but eliminating the lowest non matched value on each iteration should be a start.

Comment: FYI I figured this out in a kind of roundabout way - using the `jstack` tool that comes with the jdk to see what all the threads were doing, which led to `(range)` being called...

Comment: @noisesmith-- can you explain how you did that? before I posted this to SO, I had been googling for a Clojure library to let me do the same. I learned of a contribute.profile library but which seems to be obsolete, or at least I can't find reference to it since clojure.contrib was integrated.

Comment: `jstack` is a command line tool, you supply the PID of a jvm process, and it dumps a full stack trace of all threads to the terminal (which you can pipe to a file or pager of course)

Comment: You can also take a look at the graphical Java Mission Control tool that comes with JDK 1.7.0.40+

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other good answers here, you're doing a bunch of math, but all numbers are boxed as objects rather than being used as primitives. Many tips for doing this better [here](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Support%20for%20Java%20Primitives).

Answer (score 1):

This is a really inefficient way of counting powers of 2:

```
(filter #(zero? (bit-and % (dec %))) (range))
```

This is essentially counting from 0 to infinity, testing each number along the way to see if it's a power of two. The further you get into the sequence, the more expensive each call to `rest` is.

Given that it's the test input, and you can't change it, I think you need to re-think your approach. Rather than calling `(mapv rest coll)`, you probably only want to call `rest` on the sequence with the smallest first value.

Comment: That's actually part of the exercise, not OP's code. http://www.4clojure.com/problem/108

Comment: Which is why I explained that OP has to work out an approach that doesn't involve getting the next value from each input on each iteration.